# Assign Extracted text from HTML table to Variable for later use -- Beautiful Soup / Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-3.7, nextsibling

I have the below code working perfectly to dynamically search for a specific text within a HTML table source code and pull the nextSibling of the row where the specific text was found.

Current Code

```
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
           
# Find xxxxxxx (row-by-row) and split trailing zeros
row = soup.find_all('td', string="xxxxxxx")
for r in row:
        LE = r.nextSibling
        while LE.name != 'td' and LE is not None:
                LE = LE.nextSibling
```

The main issue I am having (it is probably super easy and I have just been staring at this for so long now) is that I need to assign the nextSibling to the LE variable.

LE is formatted as "001234" where I need to strip the leading zeros to have "1234" as the variable.

If I print the variable as `print(LE.text[2:6])` the result is correct. Implemented into the code as,
`LE = LE.nextSibling.text[2:6]` does not produce anything.

I have tried the following statements, but none work and am hoping for guidance.

```
LE = LE.nextSibling.text[2:6]
&
LE = LE.text[2:6]
```

I need this to be assigned to a variable after extracting to utilize the variable later on within my script.
I appreciate the help in advance!

EDIT --> included source code:

```
<tr>
     <td class='label' nowrap title="xxxxxxx">TEXT TO FIND</td>
     <td class='attribute'>001234</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Please share the URL

Comment: @MendelG -- I can only provide the source code as you would not be able to enter the website as it is server-based. Let me know if you need further information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

`!=` to `==`

```
 row = soup.find_all('td', string="xxxxxx")
            for r in row:
                LE = r.nextSibling
                    LE = LE.text[2:6]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `next_sibling` twice, and than use `strip()` to remove `0`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<tr>
     <td class='label' nowrap title="xxxx">TEXT TO FIND</td>
     <td class='attribute'>001234</td>
</tr>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for tag in soup.select(".label"):
    le = ''.join([t.strip("0") for t in tag.next_sibling.next_sibling])
    print(tag.text)
    print(le)
```

Output:

```
TEXT TO FIND
1234
```

Comment: Appreciate the help, but I believe I found the problem (silly mistake)-- I will post it. If I end up running into problems, I will reach out again!